# PHP Post Unset Fully

Tags: php

Okay so I found out some browsers try to be smart and remember form data even if you refresh. But if you click the url bar and hit enter it DOES fully unset the post data

Is there a way to fully unset $_POST data even if u refresh it? (Google chrome)  so it has no way of remembering.

```
 <?php 
 if (isset($_POST['loginsubmit']))
 {
     echo 'triggered';
     unset($_POST['loginsubmit']);   
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: You need to understand how HTTP works. New request = new $_POST. Don't want a certain value? Remove it from the page.

Comment: So is there a way of removing it?

Comment: So you sent a form and then you hit F5 and what makes you wonder is why browsers behave that way? Welcome to the internet, that's how it works and it's not PHP's nor anyone's fault. What you want to do is focus your browsers' URL bar and hit ENTER (SHIFT + F6 > ENTER). Not F5.

Answer (score 0):

By refreshing, you are re-sending your POST request. 
If you "hit the address bar" you do not re-send it, you simply call teh URL with a GET request. 
That is handled by your Browser, not by PHP.

You can however use [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) to prevent POST data being comitted twice.

One way to do this is to have a token in your forms, set in the session as well (simply store it in the session uppon creating the form).

If the data is submitted via POST and processed (i.e. inserted into a database) you check if the Token exists in the Session.
After processing the data you delete the token from the Session.